# catching state that is changed by execStateT

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, state, haskell-stack

I am very new to Haskell. Recently, I had to work with it for my project.

I have a certain code which is evaluating some state using `execStateT` and I want to catch each state change and return it.

I have tried to understand what execStateT and the flow of the code, but I am failing at certain places, where I couldn't understand how to get the thing I really want.
Maybe due to a somewhat RAW understanding of monads and other concepts, I am finding a need to change the whole structure of the code.

In the upcoming code, I tried to use `par` to create a file and write the state of a variable into that file, and so it doesn't affect the actual work of the code. But it didn't create a file and write the inputs into it.

I am facing the following code

```hs
campaign u v w ts d = let d' = fromMaybe defaultDict d in fmap (fromMaybe mempty) (view (hasLens . to knownCoverage)) >>= \c -> do
  g <- view (hasLens . to seed)
  let g' = mkStdGen $ fromMaybe (d' ^. defSeed) g
  execStateT (evalRandT runCampaign g') (Campaign ((,Open (-1)) <$> ts) c d') where
    step        = runUpdate (updateTest v Nothing) >> lift u >> runCampaign
    runCampaign = use (hasLens . tests . to (fmap snd)) >>= update
    update c    = view hasLens >>= \(CampaignConf tl q sl _ _) ->
      if | any (\case Open  n   -> n < tl; _ -> False) c -> callseq v w q >> step
         | any (\case Large n _ -> n < sl; _ -> False) c -> step
         | otherwise                                     -> lift u
```

What I want here is find some way to look at the changes in variable `v`, to do my further work. This can be done either by writing a variable into a file or returning it to the console.

Thanks for help!

**[Edit 1]**

Here are the imports I am making:

```hs
import Control.Lens
import Control.Monad (liftM2, replicateM, when)
import Control.Monad.Catch (MonadCatch(..), MonadThrow(..))
import Control.Monad.Random.Strict (MonadRandom, RandT, evalRandT)
import Control.Monad.Reader.Class (MonadReader)
import Control.Monad.State.Strict (MonadState(..), StateT, evalStateT, execStateT)
import Control.Monad.Trans (lift)
import Control.Monad.Trans.Random.Strict (liftCatch)
import Data.Aeson (ToJSON(..), object)
import Data.Bool (bool)
import Data.Either (lefts)
import Data.Foldable (toList)
import Data.Map (Map, mapKeys, unionWith)
import Data.Maybe (fromMaybe, isNothing, maybeToList)
import Data.Ord (comparing)
import Data.Has (Has(..))
import Data.Set (Set, union)
import Data.Text (unpack)
import EVM
import EVM.Types (W256)
import Numeric (showHex)
import System.Random (mkStdGen)
```

Comment: What packages are you using? What imports? What does `par` have to do with opening files and such? What does `par` have to do with the code you've shown? What does the hanging `otherwise` represent, if anything?

Comment: If I had to *guess* (lots of guessing!), I would guess that `StateT` is the wrong tool for you, and that what you want is a *different* `MonadState` instance that does some sort of logging. But it's a bit hard to tell what's going on from what you've given us.

Comment: Hi, I am using `par` for parallely open a file and write the states to it. I did this way

```haskell
step        = <opening file and writing to it> `par` runUpdate (updateTest v Nothing) >> lift u >> runCampaign
```

I did import `Control.Parallel`

Comment: All I want to do is, write the variable `v` (which is being updated) into a file or the console.

Comment: That's not what `par` is for at all (also, `par` is semi-deprecated; things like `rpar` and `parEval` behave better). `parallel` is all about *pure* parallel computation. You're after *concurrency", so you need something like `forkIO`, or, better, some tool from the `async` package.

Comment: `StateT` really doesn't offer what you want. Your best bet might be to combine it with some sort of logging monad transformer and write a custom `MonadState` instance for the combination.

Comment: thanks for the great knowledge @dfeuer . Let me look more into the things, and find how can I make it the way I want.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach. Suppose you have a class for monads supporting logging of messages with a certain type (`MonadLogger` is one, but I don't know enough about it to use it here). I'll just use a hypothetical `CanLog` class. Now you can write

```
newtype LStateT s m a = LStateT
  {runLStateT :: StateT s m a}
  deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad)

instance CanLog s m => MonadState s (LStateT s m) where
   get = LStateT get
   put x = LStateT $ do
     lift $ -- Log the state transition
     put x
```

Comment: Hi, I'm afraid I don't know that great haskell. But I'll try to fathom over the code you provided. Will mark the tick if it works for me. Many thanks.